# PHP: explode after n Number of lines

Tags: php, explode

I have text with multiple lines. Say, its 100 lines. Every four lines together make a single block of data. So, I want to explode data into array after every 4 lines. is there any thing in PHP to achieve this thing?

Comment: Lines in a text file or a string?

Comment: Yes, loops and conditions.

Comment: Also an example of the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly. But you can split first the data and then re-implode() it in chucks of four:

```
$split = explode("\n", $data);
while (!empty($split)) {
    $array[] = implode("\n", array_splice($split, 0, 4));
}
```

Comment: @nl-x yes, you're right, explode is guaranteed to return an array with a least one element if valid input is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$tmp = explode("\n", $data);
$fours = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i++)
    if ($i % 4 == 0)
        $fours[count($fours)] = $tmp[$i];
    else
        $fours[count($fours) - 1] .= "\n" . $tmp[$i];
```